# PHP delete error

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a dropdown list populated with files pulled from a directory using the PHP listed below and am trying to figure out how I can delete them using a delete button in the form when they're selected.

**EDIT** Unlink function error resolved.

Still getting error when trying to delete:
    Error.array(1) { ["Action"]=> string(6) "Delete" }

```
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="EDIT" /><input type="hidden" name="Selection"  id="Selection" value="-1"><div>Below is the list of your saved codes. To edit your codes, select it from the list.</div>
<select size="1" name="CodeList" id="CodeList">
<?php
   $directory = $directory = 'users/' . $_SESSION['username'];
   $filesContents = Array();
   $files = scandir( $directory ) ;

    foreach( $files as $file )
   {
  if ( ! is_dir( $file ) )
 {
   $filesContents[$file] = file_get_contents($directory , $file);
      echo '<option value="'. $file .'">' . $file . '</option>';
   }
  }
?>
```

delete php script.

```
   <?php
   session_start();
    $directory = $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/users/' .      $_SESSION['username'];
    $file_to_delete = $_POST['CodeList'];
    if(is_file($directory .'/'. $file_to_delete) && is_writable($directory .'/'. $file_to_delete)) {
    if ( unlink ($directory.'/'.$file_to_delete) ) {
      echo $file_to_delete . " deleted.";
    } else {
  echo "Error.";
  }
 }
?>
<?php var_dump($_POST) ?>
```

Comment: Do note that your `delete.php` can be abused to delete any file on your server. You must validate `$_POST['CodeList']`!

Comment: The JS for @BlackDevil is useless here...

Comment: thank you georg for catching that I will look that up how to validate it before going live after trying to fix this other error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the options, but no option *value*. A selectbox should look like this:

```
<select name="identifier">
    <option value="value_1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="value_2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Now if you select option 2, you should get value_2 in your post array:

```
echo $_POST['identifier']; // prints out 'value_2';
```

Your options look like: `<option>Option x</option>`, which means you select an option, but it has no value (no `value=""` attribute).

If you look at your PHP error, I do see a correct directory name, but there is no filename appended.

You should also check if the file exists, to prevent a "no such file" error:

```
if(is_file($directory .'/'. $file_to_be_deleted) && is_writable($directory .'/'. $file_to_be_deleted)) {
    // delete the file
}
```

Yes, I use the `is_file` AND the `is_writable` test, because the `is_writable` function will also return `true` if the checked path is a directory.

**EDIT**

To assign values, alter your foreach loop as follows:

```
<select size="1" name="CodeList" id="CodeList">
    <?php
    // fetch files etc.

    foreach( $files as $file ) {
        if ( ! is_dir( $file ) {
            echo '<option value="'. $file .'">' . $file . '</option>';
        }
    }
```

Oh and btw: get rid of the `get_file_contents()` part. You don't do anything with the contents of the file there, do you?

Comment: Thank you Giorgio for your help I'm updating my php file now, the problem with the dropdown list was not knowing I had to assign the values. The list is populated by files they save in their user directory (which could be any amount unless I limit it) so I'm unsure of how to assign them values.

Comment: Thank you Giorgio am trying that now, adding in your other string in the php cleared any errors there just returning the array error but will test that with adding the file. And once they select the file, it actually posts the file name and contents into a form on the page that why I was using get_file_contents()

Comment: ah ok, you use the contents somewhere else in the script, I get it :) In that case, ignore my comment about that (although I'll leave it there in case someone else is trying to do the same and does _not_ use the file contents explicitly)

Comment: I do I just didn't have that in there and no worries, I appreciate the mention just in case I had something wrong, trying your changes now.

Comment: I updated my original post with the coding you supplied exactly as its on my form. I don't get the unlink error anymore however nothing gets deleted and my var_dump returns: array(1) { ["Action"]=> string(6) "Delete" }

Comment: hmm... looks like the values of the selectbox are not being sent to the server. Can you post the full html of the rendered form? Just checkout the source of the browser.

Comment: sure, the code is huge so I just put the entire thing in the html box of this jfiddle so you can see everything. https://jsfiddle.net/076borbL/1/

Comment: I was able to figure it out with cleaning things up, putting the delete button in the right place and wrapping my form properly to include the dropdwown. thank you for all of your help giorgio.

Answer (score -1):

We can use Javascript for this

Remove option :

```
 $("#selectBox option[value='option1']").remove();
```

Add option :

```
 $("#selectBox").append('<option value="option5">option5</option>');
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for the assist! I'm unsure if I wrote it right, I put what I did and the result in my original post.

Comment: thank you for the clarification on the code, input it just as you have it both in the head and beneath my form and trying to delete the selected file still returns the unlink error.

Comment: my apologies on being novice, I am unsure if I need to change those option values or leave them as is.

Comment: please use file_exist() function before using unlink function